# Starting new page with 4up mode in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

I use `pgfpages` to create 4up handouts. The handout is very long (for a whole semester) and I would like to start a new page when a new session starts. What I am looking for is code that works like the code in books inserting an empty page when a new chapter starts and the new chapter would start on the wrong page.

In the MWE the three slides following 2 should be empty pages and Session 2 should start in the left top corner on a new page.

**Edit:**
Something like this `\cleardoublepage` should do the trick. But one would have to have a look at the page counter and check how many empty pages have to be inserted till the next page devidable by four. I do not know how to do the math in LaTeX. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage%
    \if@twoside%
        \ifodd\c@page%
            % do nothing
        \else%
            \emptypage@emptypage%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}%
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Stefan Müller}
\title{The great test}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]

\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth, 
  center = \pgfpoint{.275\pgfphysicalwidth}{.74\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.725\pgfphysicalwidth}{.74\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.275\pgfphysicalwidth}{.26\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
 center = \pgfpoint{.725\pgfphysicalwidth}{.26\pgfphysicalheight}
}


\begin{document}

\frame{
\maketitle
}

\frame{
0

}

\section{1}
\subtitle{Session 1}
\frame{
\maketitle
}
\frame{1}
\section{2}
\frame{2}
\subtitle{Session 2}
\frame{
\maketitle
}


\section{3}
\frame{3}
\section{4}
\frame{4}
\section{5}
\frame{5}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the current page number at the start of your subtitle and then insert empty pages as required:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Stefan Müller}
\title{The great test}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]

\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth, 
  center = \pgfpoint{.275\pgfphysicalwidth}{.74\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.725\pgfphysicalwidth}{.74\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.275\pgfphysicalwidth}{.26\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
 center = \pgfpoint{.725\pgfphysicalwidth}{.26\pgfphysicalheight}
}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\pretocmd{\subtitle}{
  {
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
   \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\thepage,4))}
   \let\foo\pgfmathresult

   \ifnum\foo=0
      \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
      \end{frame}   
   \fi      
   
   \ifnum\foo=2
      \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
      \end{frame}   
      \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
      \end{frame}   
      \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
      \end{frame}         
   \fi   
   
   \ifnum\foo=3
      \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
      \end{frame}   
      \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
      \end{frame}   
   \fi
   
  }
}{}{}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@subtitle}{\frame{\maketitle}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{
\maketitle
}

\frame{
0
\pause
abc
}

\section{1}
\subtitle{Session 1}

\frame{1}
\section{2}
\frame{2}
\subtitle{Session 2}

\section{3}
\frame{3}
\section{4}
\frame{4}
\section{5}
\frame{5}

\end{document}
```